# Need help - skipping over some serial.print statements

Tags: arduino-uno, blynk

I have a project I'm working on for a chicken coop.  I want to control the door with timing of the sunrise and sunset.  Also looking to a few other things but somewhere along the way, I must have screwed up the placement of `setup()`, `loop()` and other void statements.  I'm not longer getting `Serial.print` statements to print.  I've done quite a bit of borrowing from other codes (which might be apparent to those that are much better at this than me).  For some of those borrowed codes, I'm getting serial prints.  I'm using this as my debug, so I can verify the values that I'm passing and to determine if they are what I'm expecting, specifically for the times of sunrise and sunset, to control my door actuator.

**Any ideas why these various serial.print lines are not printing?**

I've indicated some of the serial.print lines with `<------------------------`.

```cpp
/*************************************************************
  Download latest Blynk library here:
    https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-library/releases/latest

  Blynk is a platform with iOS and Android apps to control
  Arduino, Raspberry Pi and the likes over the Internet.
  You can easily build graphic interfaces for all your
  projects by simply dragging and dropping widgets.

    Downloads, docs, tutorials: http://www.blynk.cc
    Sketch generator:           http://examples.blynk.cc
    Blynk community:            http://community.blynk.cc
    Follow us:                  http://www.fb.com/blynkapp
                                http://twitter.com/blynk_app

  Blynk library is licensed under MIT license
  This example code is in public domain.

 *************************************************************
  WARNING!
    It's very tricky to get it working. Please read this article:
    http://help.blynk.cc/hardware-and-libraries/arduino/esp8266-with-at-firmware

  This example shows how value can be pushed from Arduino to
  the Blynk App.

  NOTE:
  BlynkTimer provides SimpleTimer functionality:
    http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer

  App project setup:
    Value Display widget attached to Virtual Pin V5
 *************************************************************/

/* Comment this out to disable prints and save space */
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial


#include <ESP8266_Lib.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleShieldEsp8266.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <Dusk2Dawn.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>

#define TIMEZONE    -6
#define LATITUDE    38.3970
#define LONGITUDE   -90.6412


//The type of DHT that is being used
#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
//Which pin the DHT output is connected to the Arduino
#define DHTPIN 5
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);


// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "d*********************************0";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "P**********k";
char pass[] = "m*****************a";

int DisconnectCount = 0;
int ReCnctFlag;
int ReCnctCount = 0;

  Dusk2Dawn HouseSprings(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE, TIMEZONE);
  tmElements_t tm;
  //Changes Mins to the same format as Sunrise/Sunset (minutes after midnight)
  int Mins = tm.Hour * 60 + tm.Minute;
  int Sunrise = HouseSprings.sunrise(tm.Year, tm.Month, tm.Day, true);
  int Sunset = HouseSprings.sunset(tm.Year, tm.Month, tm.Day, true);

//char Str_door_status[] = "";

// Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro...
//#define EspSerial Serial1

// or Software Serial on Uno, Nano...
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial EspSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

// Your ESP8266 baud rate: adjust per project
#define ESP8266_BAUD 9600

ESP8266 wifi(&EspSerial);



BlynkTimer timer;

//Section of code that will handle getting the humidity/temp data and where to send it
void send_sensor()
{
  //Set the variable h to the value for humidity
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  //Set the variable f to the value for temp
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  //delay(1000);
  //Perform a check if either h or f has no value
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }
  //These would be used to send data to the serial window
  Serial.println(h); // <------------------------
  Serial.println(f); // <------------------------
  //Set the virtual pin 3 of the blynk to the temperature value
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, f);
  //Set the virtual pin 4 of the blynk to the humidity value
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V4, h);
}






// This function sends Arduino's up time every second to Virtual Pin (5).
// In the app, Widget's reading frequency should be set to PUSH. This means
// that you define how often to send data to Blynk App.
void myTimerEvent()
{
  // You can send any value at any time.
  // Please don't send more that 10 values per second.


}

int in1 = 11;
int in2 = 12;

void motor_stop()
{
  digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V6,0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V7,0);
}


BLYNK_WRITE(V6)
{
  int pinValue = param.asInt();
  pinMode(in1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2,OUTPUT);
  if (pinValue = 1);
  {
    digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0,1);
    //delay(35000);
    //digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
    //Blynk.virtualWrite(V6,0);
    timer.setTimeout(35000L, motor_stop);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0,2);
  }
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V7)
{
  int pinValue = param.asInt();
  pinMode(in1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2,OUTPUT);
  if (pinValue = 1);
  {
    digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2,HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0,1);
    //removed this delay function as Blynk doesn't like it
    //delay(35000);
    //digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
    //Blynk.virtualWrite(V6,0);
    //Secondary method of delay that Blynk appears to prefer
    timer.setTimeout(35000L, motor_stop);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V0,0);
  }
}



void setup()
{
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Set ESP8266 baud rate
  EspSerial.begin(ESP8266_BAUD);
  delay(10);

  Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, ssid, pass);
  // You can also specify server:
  //Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, ssid, pass, "blynk-cloud.com", 80);
  //Blynk.begin(auth, wifi, ssid, pass, IPAddress(192,168,1,100), 8080);

  // Setup a function to be called every second
  timer.setInterval(1000L, myTimerEvent);



  dht.begin();

  timer.setInterval(1000L, send_sensor);

  //RTC.read(tm);

  
  
}

BLYNK_CONNECTED() {
  Serial.println("Connected");
  ReCnctCount = 0;

}



      


  //Serial.println(Sunrise);  // 418
  //Serial.println(Sunset);   // 1004





void open_door()
{

}

void close_door()
{
  Serial.println("info"); // <------------------------
  Serial.println(Mins); // <------------------------
  Serial.println(Sunrise); // <------------------------
  Serial.println(Sunset); // <------------------------
  char time2[] = "00:00";
  Dusk2Dawn::min2str(time2, Sunrise);
  Serial.print("Sunrise: ");     // <------------------------
  Serial.println(time2); // 16:53  // <------------------------
  char time3[] = "00:00";
  Dusk2Dawn::min2str(time3, Sunset);
  Serial.print("Sunset: ");  // <------------------------
  Serial.println(time3); // 16:53 // <------------------------
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(Mins); // <------------------------
  Serial.println(Sunrise); // <------------------------
  Serial.println(Sunset); // <------------------------
  
  if (Blynk.connected()) 
  {
    Blynk.run();                                    // Starts Blynk connection
  }
  else if (ReCnctFlag == 0) 
  {
    ReCnctFlag = 1;                                 // Set reconnection Flag
    Serial.println("Starting reconnection timer in 3 seconds...");
    timer.setTimeout(3000L, []() {                 // Lambda Reconnection Timer Function
      ReCnctFlag = 0;                             // Reset reconnection Flag
      ReCnctCount++;                              // Increment reconnection Counter
      Serial.print("Attempting reconnection #");
      Serial.println(ReCnctCount);
      Blynk.connect();                            // Try to reconnect to the server
    });
  }
  timer.run(); // Initiates BlynkTimer


  
  //if (Mins > Sunrise) {
    //Serial.println("Door is open"); 
  //}
  //if (Mins > Sunset) {
  //  Serial.println("Door is closed");
  //}


  
}
```

This is what I'm getting in the serial window:

```
[45108333] Ready (ping: 53ms). 
Connected
```

Comment: Not sure why the code posted weird, sorry for the mess.  Everything ran together from separate lines.

Comment: You can see what I did in the [edit history](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/82158/revisions).  In short, backticks rather than single-quote characters.  I've changed your attempt at bolding the print statements to indicating them with an arrow in a comment because formatting doesn't place nice with code listings.

Comment: I notice in the code is the use of `3` in `SoftwareSerial EspSerial(2, 3);` which seems to be `Serial`'s RX pin.  But a severely cut down version of your code doing nothing but this didn't seem cause the problem.  My only suggestion is that you start removing code from your question, starting with things that people who might try to help you are not going to want to deal with.  Blynk, the DHT sensor, whatever you can remove while still demonstrating the problem.

Comment: put in lots of serial.print statements to determine where the program hangs

Comment: you can call Serial.begin() again to "fix" it and see if something else breaks. I'm guessing something is trying to digitalWrite to the serial pin.

Comment: @timemage, this is a sketch for Uno

Comment: try `#define BLYNK_NO_BUILTIN` before `#include <BlynkSimpleShieldEsp8266.h>`

Comment: @Juraj, yeah, that does make more sense.  Without a pile of stuff removed, I'm not going to get much use out of that information though.